# Hyphen in MATCH AGAINST Fulltext MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4, mariadb-10.3

I have DB table PERSON something like below

```
|ID  |FIRST_NAME    |LAST_NAME|
|1   |Peter-Parkar  |Williams |
|2   |Peter Panatano|Williams |
|3   |Peter-Pant    |Nati     |
```

I want to search and get the first name result using this query

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME) as PERSON_NAME 
FROM PERSON 
WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST ('peter-p*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I would like to get the results "Peter-Parkar Williams" and "Peter-Pant Nati", but it is not giving as I expected. How to get that result?

Note: I don't want to use "LIKE" operator in this case, strictly want answers with MATCH AGAINST.

Comment: How is  `FIRST_NAME` defined in your schema, did you use FULLTEXT

Comment: It is VARCHAR. This is the most exact query I am using SELECT concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as person_name
WHERE (
 MATCH(text) AGAINST ('peter-p*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
 )

Comment: If you didnt define as FULLTEXT you cannot use MATCH

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be that specific about first and last names, you must keep them in separate columns.  (Note:  There are two-word first names and two-word last names.)

In `FULLTEXT`, you can possibly change whether `-` is punctuation or not -- see the specific settings for your version of MySQL/MariaDB and Engine (MyISAM vs InnoDB).

In the columnar approach

```
WHERE first_name LIKE 'peter-p%'
   with
INDEX(first_name)
```

is quite efficient.

Another approach to use the speed of a `FULLTEXT` index for this case:

```
WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST ('peter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND text LIKE '%peter-p%'
```

That would use the index speed to narrow down the search to rows with "peter", then check to see if "-p" followed it.